# Why is LookupsClient undefined?

Tags: twilio

I'm using twilio 3.0.0. On it's own, I am able to send SMS messages. However, when I integrated LookupsClient to verify phone numbers, I get the error "`TypeError: LookupsClient is not a constructor`"

I've tried many variations of the code below, but none seem to work because LookupsClient is undefined.

Does anyone know why this might be?

```
var Twilio = require('twilio');

var accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
var authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

var twilio = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);


var LookupsClient = twilio.LookupsClient;

console.log('LookupsClient is', LookupsClient); // This line logs LookupsClient is undefined

var lookupsClient = new LookupsClient(accountSid, authToken);
var phoneNumbers = lookupsClient.phoneNumbers(phoneNumber);
phoneNumbers.get(function(error, number) {
  console.log('error is ', error);
  console.log('number is ', number);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing up SDK v2 and SDK v3 objects. SDK v3.X is the current version. You should use something like the following:

```
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.lookups.v1
    .phoneNumbers('+15108675309')
    .fetch()
    .then((number) => console.log(number.carrier.type, number.carrier.name));
```

Please see the documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups?code-sample=code-lookup-with-e164-formatted-number&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x

You can also see an example of the (deprecated) v2 syntax there as well. Use the small 2.X selector near the top right.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Lookups is also undefined.

Comment: hmmm sorry. Try `Twilio.Lookups`

Comment: No luck there either :/ Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Please mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm no longer getting errors, but the carrier name and type are showing up as null.